# New window label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

how do I position my label which says "Question One" in my def new_window() function. As you run it the label is being positioned at the bottom, And i want it to be applied on the top.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


#User Interface Code

root = Tk() # Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")

def new_window():
   newWindow = Toplevel(root)
   display = Label(newWindow, width=150, height=40)
   message = Label(newWindow, text="Question One", font = ("Arial", "24"))
   display.pack()
   message.pack()

display2 = Label(root, width=100, height=30, bg='green')
button1 = Button(root, text ="Continue", command=new_window, width=16, 
bg="red")
message_label1 = Label(text="A Quiz Game", font = ("Arial", "24"), padx=40, 
pady=20)
message_label2 = Label(root, text="Click 'Continue' to begin.", 
wraplength=250)

display2.pack()
button1.pack()
message_label1.pack()
message_label2.pack()

root.mainloop() # Runs the main window loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are packing in the wrong order. Do not pack display `before` your `message`. So just swapping the order will fix the issue.

Here is the code. Replace your `def new_window():` with this

```
def new_window():
   newWindow = Toplevel()

   message = Label(newWindow, text="Question One", font = ("Arial", "24"))
   display = Label(newWindow, width=150, height=40)

   message.pack()
   display.pack()
```

`pack` method just blindly packs the widget into the window. And the next `pack` will be done below it if there is space. So take care of the order while packing widgets :)